# Add content to a table cell except if a child class is present in that row

Tags: jquery

I have a table of events. Some are ongoing and some have a specific date. The specific date is shown when the event has a date, but I need to add the text 'Ongoing Program' to the empty cells where the date would be.

The snippet I have been working on looks for the class `tb2-day` and should add my text to cells that don't have that class on a child element. However, it is adding the text to all cells. How can I fix this?

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery(".product-type-simple").each(function() {
    if ($(this).find('.tb2-day').length) {
      jQuery('<p>Ongoing<br>Program</p>').appendTo('.we-first-row');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="we-table">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="product-type-simple">
      <td class="we-first-row"></td>
      <td>content</td>
      <td class="tb-viewdetails">
        <a class="btn" href="#">info</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="product-type-simple">
      <td class="we-first-row"></td>
      <td>content</td>
      <td class="tb-viewdetails">
        <a class="btn" href="#">info</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="product-type-simple">
      <td class="we-first-row">
        <span class="tb2-day">07</span>
        <span class="tb2-month">June</span>
      </td>
      <td>content</td>
      <td class="tb-viewdetails">
        <span>
          <a class="btn" href="#">info</a>
        </span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do what you require you can create a selector to specifically target the first `td` in each row which *does not* contain a `.tb2-day` element:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  $(".product-type-simple:not(:has(.tb2-day)) td:nth-child(1)").html('<p>Ongoing<br>Program</p>');
});
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 2px 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="we-table">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="product-type-simple">
      <td class="we-first-row"></td>
      <td>content</td>
      <td class="tb-viewdetails">
        <a class="btn" href="#">info</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="product-type-simple">
      <td class="we-first-row"></td>
      <td>content</td>
      <td class="tb-viewdetails">
        <a class="btn" href="#">info</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="product-type-simple">
      <td class="we-first-row">
        <span class="tb2-day">07</span>
        <span class="tb2-month">June</span>
      </td>
      <td>content</td>
      <td class="tb-viewdetails">
        <span>
          <a class="btn" href="#">info</a>
        </span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Note that I only amended the padding in CSS to make the UI fit better in to the snippet preview.